# How to run specific rpm scripts in child package.json in pnpm

Tags: package.json, pnpm

So please forgive this question if there is an obvious answer.  I'm new to pnpm and trying to figure out how to run a script in a lower package.json

```
/package.json
/apps
 |
  -/apps
    |
     -/subRepo1
    |
     -/subRepo2
       |
        -/package.json
```

So, in pnpm monorepo with two sub repos (each with separate package.json), how do you run a script defined in the subRepo2/package.json?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a [workspace](https://pnpm.io/workspaces) then you can use [filtering](https://pnpm.io/filtering). For instance, by package name:

```bash
pnpm --filter <subRepo2PkgName> run <script_name>
# or
pnpm --filter <subRepo2PkgName> <script_name>
# or
pnpm -F <subRepo2PkgName> <script_name>
```